# Custom badge issue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an view which is having a button and a label.
The label increments whenever the user adds items to the cart, which is done by using `custom badge.` But what I need to know is how to put onClick for that label. Button takes the onClick but label is not taking an action(UIGuesture).

I have attached the image where in clicking on the cart goes to another view, but clicking on label does not work.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Share some code : Selector invoked on button tap, and how actually you have assigned your view (containing the badge). Additionally, is it a tabBarItem, or a simple UIView added in a subview.viewController ?

Comment: So, you need to set action method for UILabel. right?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the user interaction on label.

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

By default user interaction is disabled on `UILabel`, which doesn't let any gesture to be recognized while applied on `UILabel`.

Better to use an open-source implementation:

- [MKNumberBadgeView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mknumberbadgeview)
- [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge)